# Can I ensure RVO for reintrepret-cast'ed values?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, return-value-optimization

Suppose I've written:

```
Foo get_a_foo() {
    return reinterpret_cast<Foo>(get_a_bar());
}
```

and suppose that `sizeof(Foo) == sizeof(Bar)`.

Does return value optimization necessarily take place here, or are compilers allowed to do whatever they like when I "break the rules" by using a reinterpret_cast? If I don't get RVO, or am not guaranteed it - can I change this code to ensure that it occur?

My question is about C++11 and, separately, C++17 (since there was some change in it w.r.t. RVO, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it can't be, otherwise this wouldn't compile.

Comment: "or are compilers allowed to do whatever they like when I 'break the rules'" - Yes, in full generality, the compiler can do what it wants when you have undefined behavior. In this case, unless `Foo` is a pointer, reference, integer, or enumeration type, the result is likely to be a compile error. If it is one of those, then you probably don't need RVO because your return value is trivially copyable and small, and in most architectures will go in a register.

Comment: If you have a specific example, you can find out what *actual* compilers will do on *actual* hardware. Then either hope that behavior is stable for the life of your program and you didn't miss a combination in testing, or look for flags which affect which behaviors are undefined (like the various flags to turn off the strict aliasing rule) and use those. If you go with that last option you need to read the compiler manuals for the answers and you're no longer talking about standard C++.

Comment: My understanding is that compiler implementations in C++11 are allowed to perform RVO but there is nothing to guarantee it.

Comment: @the4thamigo_uk: Yup, prior to C++17, [it was allowed, but not guaranteed](https://jonasdevlieghere.com/guaranteed-copy-elision/). The C++17 guarantees mean you can write standards-compliant code where a type lacks both move and copy constructor, but can still be returned from a function by value; in C++11, that wasn't compliant, because compilers without RVO were allowed to move or copy it, in C++17, they *must* RVO it. Sadly, the guarantee doesn't apply to NRVO, because the rules for NRVO are more complex, so in practice, you probably shouldn't disable copy/move for funsies. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Suppose I've written:
>
> ```
> Foo get_a_foo() {
>     return reinterpret_cast<Foo>(get_a_bar());
> }
> ```
>
> and suppose that `sizeof(Foo) == sizeof(Bar)`.

That `reinterpret_cast` is not legal for all possible `Foo` and `Bar` types. It only works for cases where:

1. `Bar` is a pointer and `Foo` is either a pointer or an integer/enum big enough to hold pointers.
2. `Bar` is an integer/enum big enough to hold a pointer, and `Foo` is a pointer.
3. `Bar` is an object type and `Foo` is a reference type.

There are a couple of other cases I didn't cover, but they're either irrelevant (`nullptr_t` casting) or fall under similar issues for #1 or #2.

See, elision doesn't actually matter when dealing in fundamental types. You can't tell the difference between eliding a copy/move of fundamental types and not eliding it. So is there a conversion there? Is the compiler just using the return value register? That's up to the compiler, via the "as if" rule.

And elision doesn't apply when returning reference types, so #3 is out.

But if `Foo` and `Bar` are user-defined object types (or object types other than pointers, integers, or member pointers), the cast is [is *ill-formed*](https://www.ideone.com/45MjhS). `reinterpret_cast` is not some kind of trivial `memcpy` conversion function.

So let's replace this with some code that could, you know, actually work:

```
Foo get_a_foo()
{
    return std::bit_cast<Foo>(get_a_bar());
}
```

Where [C++20's `std::bit_cast`](http://wg21.link/P0476) effectively converts one trivial copyable type to another trivial copyable type.

That conversion still would not be elided. Or at least, not in the way "elision" is typically used.

Because the two types are trivially copyable, and `bit_cast` will only call trivial constructors, the compiler could certainly erase the constructors, and even use the return value object of `get_a_foo` as the return value object of `get_a_bar`. And thus, it could be considered "elision".

But "elision" typically refers to the part of the standard that allows the implementation to disregard even non-trivial constructor/destructors. The compiler can only perform the above because all of the constructors and destructors are trivial. If they were non-trivial, they could not be disregarded (then again, if they were non-trivial, `std::bit_cast` *wouldn't work*).

My point is that the optimization of the conversion above is not due to "elision" or RVO rules; it's due entirely to the "as if" rule. Even in C++17, whether the `bit_cast` call is effectively made a noop is entirely up to the compiler. Yes, after having created the `Foo` prvalue, the "elision" of it's copy into the function's return value object is required by C++17.

But the conversion itself is not a matter of elision.